# Fetching Remote Windows System Information From Linux Server

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, windows

I need a script/command that would fetch Windows System Information (Host Name,User Name, Domain, OS Info, Hardware Info, Memory Info, processor Info, etc) by running it on a Linux Server (RHEL 6.5 preferably).

I have already written a batch script using `wmic` that would record all above details and ran it on a Windows Server, but it won't work for Linux systems. A bash script with a series of `dmidecode` commands can fetch remote Linux systems' details, but all Windows systems will be skipped. In brief, the scope of using those scripts is limited to Windows-Windows or Linux-Linux environment.

Is there any possible way with which we can fetch all the mentioned parameters of remote Windows systems by running a script on a Linux server or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the WMI Client package?  Atomic looks to have a build for RedHat.

```
# wget -q -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic | sh
# yum install wmi
# wmic -U username%password //servername "Select * from Win32_Process"
```

Ref: http://www.krenger.ch/blog/wmi-commands-from-linux/